# Snapchat QR Code: user flow for viewing on mobile web?

Tags: mobile-website, snapchat

Goal: use Snapchat's QR codes to gain followers by adding Snapchat ghosty QR code to website

Desktop web experience:

1. user goes to site on desktop, sees ghosty
2. user takes picture of desktop site and becomes a follower

Mobile web experience

1. user goes to site on their phone or tablet
2. pulls out second phone ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does anyone know the best practices for the mobile web view of a Snapchat QR code?